# Can I view convolutional neural network as fully connected neural network

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation

for example,there is a image of 3 by 3,

and a convolutional neural network that has two 2x2 filters convolves the image

in the end,the output dimention is 2x2x2

**Can I view the above procedure as the followings?**

because of 2x2 filter,after sliding over whole image,I get  4 small images

and use these 4 small images as input of a fully connected neural network

in the end,I can also get 8 output

I don't really know back propagation in CNN, so I am trying to understand it from classic fully connected neural network.

**By inputting a small image,we can update the weights in the  fully connected neural network once,is it the same thing that updating weights of filters  in CNN ?**

Am I thinking it right?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes. You can see CNN as (among other possible interpretations):

- neural net with convolutional operation and gradients computed directly for it (typical approach)
- a fully connected network with **weight sharing**, so for simplicity lets assume that input is 1d of size 3 and you have kernel of size 2, so it looks like

  [X1 X2 X3] conv [w1 w2] = [X1w1+X2w2 X2w1+X3w3]

  which is equivalent to having a fully connected network with weights vij meaning "weight between ith input neuron and jth hidden"

  ```
  X1
  X2     h1 = X1v11+X2v21+X3v31
  X3     h2 = X1v12+X2v22+X3v32
  ```

  thus if you put `v31=v12=0` and `v11=v22`, `v21=v32` you get exactly the same network. By equality I mean literally that this is **the same variable** (thus the term weight sharing).
- collection of small neural networks (again, with **weight sharing**) which are connected to different, small patches of input (which you are proposing). So your whole model looks like:

  ```
                     /-patch 1 -- shared fully connected net\ 
  Input --splitting----patch 2 -- shared fully connected net--merging---
                     .                                      .
                     .                                      . 
                     \-patch K -- shared fully connected net/
  ```

These are just three views of the same object, in both cases if you compute the partial derivatives (gradients) you will end up with **exactly the same** equations.